# how to read a 32 bit std_logic_vector data from a text file in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to read 32bit signed number from a text file and store that in a variable. I have program for integer read but it is not working for std_logic_vector type.

Answer (score 0):

With VHDL-2008, it can be done like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

architecture syn of tb is
begin
  process is
    file txt_file   : text;
    variable line_v : line;
    variable slv_v  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable good_v : boolean;
  begin
    -- Write text file with std_logic_vector
    file_open(txt_file, "test.txt", write_mode);
    slv_v := X"1234" & "XXXXXXXX" & "ZZZZZZZZ" ;
    write(line_v, slv_v);
    writeline(txt_file, line_v);
    file_close(txt_file);
    -- Read text file with std_logic_vector
    file_open(txt_file, "test.txt", read_mode);
    readline(txt_file, line_v);
    report "line_v: " & line_v.all;
    read(line_v, slv_v, good_v);
    file_close(txt_file);
    -- Done
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

The "test.txt" text file then contains:

> 0001001000110100XXXXXXXXZZZZZZZZ

With VHDL-2002, the `std_logic_vector` is not supported in `write`/`read` procedures, but the Synopsys package `ieee.std_logic_textio` can be used to provide procedures with:

```
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
```